# Hot to disable WildFly 26.0.1 bytecode transformation from javax to jakarta packages

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, transformation, bytecode

We are using **WildFly 26.0.1** with **Java 17**. When you deploy a **WAR** file, **WildFly** inspects all **JAR** files contained in the **WAR**, and **modifies** all compiled class files (**.class**) that reference "**javax.**" packages, replacing them by their corresponding "**jakarta.**" package. This automatic bytecode transformation process creates 2 problems for us:

1. The **signatures** of all modified **JAR** files **become invalid**, and the JVM refuses to load and execute them. JAR signatures are the only reliable method we have found to ensure that our software is not tampered by our clients, hackers and/or viruses.
2. Some **JAR** files contained in the **WAR** are not meant to be executed by **WildFly**. Instead, they are downloaded to the client station using the **Java Web Start (JNLP)** technology, and are executed by a **Java 1.8 (JRE)** with "**javax.**" packages. For security reasons, JNLP does not load and execute a downloaded JAR file **that is not properly signed**. Also, we don't want these **JAR** files to use "**jakarta.**" packages.

We know which **JAR** files are used by the **client** with "**javax.**" packages, and which **JAR** files are executed by **WildFly** with "**jakarta.**" packages. So, the question is: how do you **disable** this bytecode transformation process that **WildFly** executes when you deploy a **WAR** file?

Comment: Why not just do the repackaging yourselves, in your own build process, before signing the jars?

Comment: Our build process properly compiles, packages and signs all JAR files contained in the WAR. Some JAR files are for JEE use, and some are for client use. As I mentioned before, it is WildFly that modifies the WAR file when you deploy it, invalidating the signatures of all JAR files (either for client or JEE use).

Comment: Also, whether we like it or not, WildFly will replace references to “javax.” packages by “jackarta.” packages in all JAR files, including the ones downloaded and used by the client. But the client is executing Java 1.8 with the standard “javax.” packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using WildFly Preview. The deployment transformer can be disabled by setting the `org.wildfly.unsupported.skip.jakarta.transformer` system property to `true`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That was the almost the solution. I say "almost" because the property "org.wildfly.unsupported.skip.jakarta.transformer" must be set to "true" and not "false".

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I fixed the answer.