# how to disbale the deployement transfer in wildfly in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, deployment, wildfly

I've seen an answer to diable the org.wildfly.unsupported.skip.jakarta.transformer property by putting true but I dont know who to do this with steps. Can someone please tell me the steps to do this. I'm trying to achieve this solution.
[Hot to disable WildFly 26.0.1 bytecode transformation from javax to jakarta packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164611/hot-to-disable-wildfly-26-0-1-bytecode-transformation-from-javax-to-jakarta-pack)

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I'm using wildfly 26

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to disable bytecode transformation in WildFly 26 unless you are using WildFly 26 Preview. WildFly 26 is still Jakarta EE 8, while WildFly 26 Preview is Jakarta EE 9.1.

If you're using Jakarta EE 8 it's best to stick with WildFly 26 and not use the Preview edition.

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins.. also can you please clarify if I can go with Wildfly 27 ?

Comment: Have you migrated to Jakarta EE 10? If so then yes, if not then you cannot without using the transformer which does not ship with WildFly 27 by default.